# Netty 3.3.x breaks compatibility with Java5

Tags: netty

I've discovered a compatibility problem with Netty and Java5. The "String" class in Java 5 does not support specifing the charset using the "Charset" class but only with the charset name expressed as String (eg. constructor, getBytes).

I've seen at least two different places,

- "QueryStringDecoder" at line 380
- "WebSocketServerHandshaker13" at line 22

where the code breaks when executed in a Java 5 environment

Is it possible having a 3.3.2 build that fix the problem for those who cannot upgrade to Java 6 in a short time but needs to use netty 3.3.x?

Thanks

Comment: why you cant upgrade to 3.4.x ?

Comment: I'm compiling netty by myself in order to disable the use of the "Unsafe" class (applying a small patch in UnsafeDetectionUtil), because that cause serious problem in a VM that I cannot upgrade at the moment. But I cannot compile the 3.4 branch because of the Java7 compiler required, so I compile the 3.3 branch after patching (and fixing the charset bugs for Java5). If you know any other trick to disable the use of the Unsafe class, I'll be very happy to upgrade do 3.4 branch. In alternative, is it possible for you to consider releasing a 3.4 version which permit disabling Unsafe?

Comment: In the latest 3.4.x code base we fallback to disable unsafe if we can not use it. This will be released as 3.4.1 hopefully at end of the week. The java 7 is only needed for compile, you can still run with java5 as we disable /enable features based on the jaa version on runtime

Comment: How is the check to detect if you can use it Unsafe or not? I know that Java7 is only needed for compiling but until there is no way for me to programmatically disable Unsafe, I have to compile Netty by myself with Java6

Comment: Unsafe is used only in the LinkedTransferQueue. If it fails to instance it it use LegacyLinkedTransferQueue which not use Unsafe.

Comment: It's the same behaviour that 3.3.x. The problem is that in my VM Unsag class is present and does not fail to instance, but when it's used it reports to me an invalid memory access, like I posted in another question a couple of days ago. That's the reason why I'd like to have a way to programmatically disable it.

Comment: Please open a issue in netty's bugtracker for that. I think we could introduce a System property which can disable it. Anyway like I said its a jdk bug and you should maybe just upgrade the jvm. But I can also see that it can be useful to disable it.

Comment: Ok it will now be possible to disable the use of Unsafe via a System property in the next 3.4.1.Final release. See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/272.

Comment: Great! Thank you Norman!

Comment: 3.4.1.Final is out now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade to netty-3.4.1.Final once it is out. It will fix all your problems as we now also support to disable the use of Unsafe. Just add "-Dorg.jboss.netty.tryUnsafe=false" to the startup script.